# Enable source mapping on CRA with typescript and webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, source-maps, developer-tools

I recently converted my create-react-app to typescript. I've lost the feature where I could see the file name when viewing the console in developer tools.

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
"target": "ES2018", 
"module": "commonjs",    
"checkJs": false,  
"jsx": "react", 
"sourceMap": true, 
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,  
"skipLibCheck": true, 
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
```

I'm a bit overwhelmed by the size of my `webpack.config.js` file (I think it was generated when I created my CRA). Here are some sections:

```js
{
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
...
 module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
}
```

How do I get my dev tools to show the actual files where errors are coming from?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what eslint, babel, etc are actually doing. I feel like I'm going to have to start again from scratch, but would rather avoid spending the days figuring it all out if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to have 2 separate webpack configs. Then use [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) to join them.

- Make sure to set `mode` in either of those:
  dev:
  `{..., mode: 'development', ... }`
  prod:
  `{..., mode: 'production', ... }`
- set `devtools` to `eval-source-map` in `development`, and to whatever you prefer in `production`
- `sourceMap` to `true` in `tsconfig` (as you do)

Check webpack 5(I presume this is what you have) [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) on devtooling.